# Node.js saving emojis to mysql as question marks

Tags: mysql, node.js

I can store emojis with php pdo at same hosting - database. But i'm not able to do it with node js.

Im using code below for myqsl connettion with Node js. But when i tried to save text with emoji, emojis saving to database as quesiton mark.

```
 var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'db_user',
    password: 'db_password',
    database: 'db_name',
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
});


  con.connect(
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: ");
            throw err;
        } else {
            con.query('INSERT INTO messages (message_from, message_to,message) VALUES (?, ?, ?);', [message_from, message_to,message_text],
                function (err, results, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else console.log('Inserted ' + results.affectedRows + ' row(s).');
                });
            con.end(
                function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
        }
    });
```

i also tried

```
collation: "utf8mb4_general_ci",
```

but not working anyway.

Edit: Table and data type also utf8mb4

[image]

Comment: please add a create table for messages, if both sides had utf8mb4, this should be a problem

Comment: I added photo. Both sides utf8mb4

Comment: your foto shows a different collation try it with same collation

Comment: Please add `utf8mb4_general_ci`. I had this same issue and I had changed the column collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci` and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed collation as comments says and it worked.

"utf8mb4_general_ci" to "utf8mb4_turkish_ci".